# qbs - reporting errors to Qt creator

Tags: qt-creator, qbs

I have a rule to compile glsl to SPIR-V using glslangValidator.

```
FileTagger {
    patterns: [
        "*.vert",
        "*.tesc",
        "*.tese",
        "*.geom",
        "*.frag",
        "*.comp"
    ]
    fileTags: ["glsl"]
}
Rule {
    inputs: ["glsl"]
    Artifact {
        filePath: input.fileName + ".spv"
        fileTags: ["spv"]
    }
    prepare: {
        var cmd = new Command("glslangValidator", ["-o", output.filePath, "-V", input.filePath]);
        cmd.description = "compiling " + input.fileName;
        cmd.highlight = "compiler";
        return [cmd];
    }
}
```

This works well when the input files are valid, but when there's an error glslangValidator prints the error to STDOUT instead of STDERR and returns a non-zero value. The build fails (as it should) because of the return value, but the file and line number and such are not detected by the issues pane in Qt Creator because they where printed to STDOUT instead of STDERR.

I tired using stderrFilterFunction and stdoutFilterFunction but I can't seem to find a way to pass info between them.

Is there any way to get the issues reported by glslangValidator to be detected by Qt Creator?

Comment: I switched to using glslc instead of glslangValidator. glslc outputs to STDERR so everything works as it should. I'm going to leave this question unanswered as there may be other instances of compilers outputing errors to STDOUT instead of STDERR.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should file a bug report for that tool.
As a workaround, you could switch to a JavaScriptCommand and use qbs.Process there (http://doc.qt.io/qbs/jsextension-process.html). Of course, this is a little less convenient, so you have to decide whether the issues showing up in Qt Creator is worth that.
The code would look something like this:

```
var cmd = new JavaScriptCommand();
cmd.sourceCode = function() {
    var p = new Process();
    var exitCode = p.exec("glslangValidator", ["-o", output.filePath, "-V", input.filePath]);
    var stdout = p.readStdOut();
    p.close();
    if (exitCode !== 0)
        throw stdout;
    console.info(stdout);
};
```

Comment: There are already bug reports for glslangValidator but they were closed. The authors of the tool think that STDERR should be for problems with the tool itself while STDOUT should be for errors in the glsl source.

Comment: The workaround prints the errors to the issues tab, but even when formatted as a gcc style error, it doesn't detect the file path and line number.